# Is there any way to use mods in Minecraft demo version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How can I use mods in Minecraft demo version? Can [**NTBExplorer**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) do what I am talking about?

Before that when I didn't know that mods don't run in demo version, I wasted a lot of time trying to use mods but nothing useful.

Comment: I don"t think so, but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the mod. Usually they are not made to be run in demo mode and that's usually not considered when developing them. It might work, it might fail.

When you install Forge, it puts a modified game in the folder that the launcher accesses. The launcher still passes the information that you don't have an account on to it. Forge could ignore that and just let you play the full version, but I don't think it does. Also a mod could do that, but I don't know any that do it.

I have two pieces of advice for you:

1. If you are experienced enough in the game that you already want to play with mods, I would recommend just buying the full game. The demo mode is intended to just let you try it out for one hour.
2. Just try it! I'm 99.9% sure that your PC won't catch fire. ;)

Comment: The 00.1% is more dangerous than you think!

Answer (score -5):

if you don't want to install forge make a demo world and  cleck esc when entered world then open to lan and enable cheats plus set gamemode to creative then go back to world go to chat and type `/GameMode 1` to give you creative and if you want unlimited time just watch this

otherwise, if you want all that plus mods and shaders install forge then install optifine, then click the windows start button and are at the same time and type in the box that comes up type %appdata%, and file explorer will pop up then click on .minecraft and make a folder called mods if there isnt one already and put optifine in it plus whatever mods you like. if you want shaders download a shader then click windows start and r at same time, then go to .minecraft then make a folder called shaderpacks (all lower caps) and put the shader in it then after your done with all that restart your computer and voila it works like the real version except multplayer (it works on lan just not out of your wifi connection)

Comment: Please put some effort into spelling, grammar, and paragraphs.  As it stands, this is a large mess that will take a ton of effort to untangle.